# HTML/CSS Renderer for Metro-Style Apps

Tags: c++, html, directx, windows-8, windows-runtime

The current WebView for Metro-Style apps is unusable for me because it is hosted in a seperate HWND, making it impossible to overlay the WebView with other controls. Additionally, the APIs provided are not enough for me to use it (e.g. no possibilty to handle the "onNavigation" events).

I am looking for a C++ library that can parse HTML/CSS and render using DirectX. I am willing to write my own renderer but it is not easy. I would help to atleast have a proper HTML/CSS parser.

I also checked if I can use Gecko or Webkit but they would fail store approval (also they are highly complicated and a little bit overkill for my project.)

Additional requirements:

- non-GPL (must be allowed in closed-source commercial apps.)
- XHTML complaint parser/renderer
- source code availability is a plus. Otherwise binaries for x86 & ARM required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new WebView in Windows 8.1 has solved all of the issues I previously had. Mixing the new WebView in XAML apps can be done without any airspace issues (even multiple WebViews can be placed over each other). 
Since none of the mentioned solutions really solve my issue (not compatible with Metro-Style apps), I have choosen to answer my own question for other people looking for information.

MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at LibRocket or Awesomium. They're in the right ballpark.