# can other control cover on webview

Tags: webview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

WebView has the characteristic that other UI regions such as controls cannot be rendered on top of the WebView.

Does this mean that there is no way I can put other control (like popup ) on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Currently, (25.04.2012) there is no way to overlay the WebView provided in the public SDK for Windows 8. The problem is basically that the WebView is technically a instance of Internet Explorer running in its own HWND inside of other Metro Style apps. Actually, the WebView is not a proper XAML control at all.

If you need to show static (non-interactive) HTML in your app, you can use the WebViewBrush.

I am currently looking for a solution myself: [HTML/CSS Renderer for Metro-Style Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297772/html-css-renderer-for-metro-style-apps)

Basically, we have the following options right now:
- MSFT "fixes" the WebView Control
- Other Browser vendors (Mozilla, Google, Opera, etc.) provide a reuseable XAML Control
- We develop our own port of WebKit

Maybe someday, the issue will be resolved...

See my thread here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/23a235a2-b0a3-4161-bc74-c42289c61264
Other ressources:
http://nerddawg.blogspot.de/

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a new class, there is a class called WebViewBrush for this purpose. Here is the link.
[WebViewBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush)